# elastic Aggregation one result

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to group by a property and only get the cheapest returned in the result.

When I have the following information in an elastic index:

**Name | price | type**

- bear | 15 | animal
- bal  | 4  | toy
- duck | 10 | animal
- bear | 13 | animal
- doll | 16 | toy
- dog  | 20 | animal

I would like the following as the result

**Name | price | type**

- duck | 10 | animal
- bal  | 4  | toy

I've tried to get such a result with the following query:

```
    {
        "aggregations": {
            "aggregation_1": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "type.keyword",
                    "order": {
                        "price_min": "desc"
                    },
                        "size": 5
                },
                "aggregations": {
                    "price_min": {
                        "min": {
                            "field": "price"
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        },
        "size": 10
    }
```

But the results from that query returns all items, is aggregation the wrong method to get what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do it like this, i.e. for each product type, find the hit with the lowest price:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "aggregation_1": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "type.keyword",
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "cheapest": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {
              "price": "asc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's seems to be exactly the result I want yes. And even when I also add a query the aggregation result uses that also.

Comment: Yes, if you add a query, the aggregations will only be performed on the matching documents.